# Crash while reading from a table view

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I am having a table view named `Symbols_Master`

I am trying to get data from this view using C#. Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection connMits = new SqlConnection("test\\dev05;Initial Catalog=xyz;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "select top 2000 Name from Symbols_Master where TypeID=10 and Active=1";
command.Connection = connMits;

//Option 1: 
SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
myAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

//Option 2:   
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

//Option 3:
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I have tried 3 different ways for executing this query as wriiten above, but none of these are working. I always get a crash `Additional information: Invalid object name 'Symbols_Master'.`

Am I doing something wrong here or is there any other approach I should follow to read a view?

Comment: Specify schema for view. Probably your view has different schema than `dbo` or your user you use to connect has different default schema. Or simply your view does not exists

Comment: You initial catalog in the connection string is abc.  The initial catalog is the database name which is not needed if you include it in the SQL statement with a USE statement.

Comment: @ jdweng, abc is just an example, I have actually written database name in my code.

Comment: @ lad2025, its dbo schema and using same connection, if I execute a query on tables, it works fine. View also exists as I can see in SQL management studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like either your view does not exist or you are checking it in the wrong database. You probably need to specify your database name in your connection string like this:

```
const string sStr = "Server = MYSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = YOURDATABASE; Integrated Security = SSPI";
```

So it would be something like this in your case:

```
SqlConnection connMits = new SqlConnection("Server = MYSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = YOURDATABASE;Initial Catalog=xyz;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: I was looking into wrong database. I wasn't much aware about SqlConnection string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "Symbols_Master" is not available. Make sure that the table exists. The connection string may be wrong. Check the case sensitivity. Run the command from Sql Management Studio.